# Are header files only for classes?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C ++ and I have a question about header files. Are they only for classes? If I have some functions and want to use them in several files, should I write the declaration in the h file and the definition in the cpp file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: No,  you can use them to declare functions, enums ...

Comment: ***should I write the declaration in the h file and the definition in the cpp file?*** Yes

Comment: Headers define an interface. That interface could be for just about anything.

Comment: Headers are used all the time in C which doesn't even *have* classes.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: That's kinda backwards, it sounds restrictive when the actual rule is expansive.  Headers are generally the place for all declarations (template or not).  The important interaction is that for template functions, headers are the place for definitions in addition to declarations.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair, I wrote that a bit confusingly. I'll just delete it and let your comment stand